# P-series convergence - problem understanding mistake

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Why the second approach yields different result? I can't figure it out.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n^2+3}-n}{n^{p}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2+3-n^2}{(\sqrt{n^2+3}+n)n^{p}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3}{(\sqrt{n^2+3}+n)n^{p}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3}{(\sqrt{2n^2}+n)n^{p}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3}{n(\sqrt{2}+1)n^{p}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}+1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}$$

This obviously converges for p>0

But my real problem is with understanding what is the mistake if I'd want to try it the following way:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n^2+3}-n}{n^{p}}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{(n+1)^2}-n}{n^{p}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{p}}$$

It seems I'm missing some fundamental mistake but I just can't see it. Help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach shows that the series converges if $p>1$.  This is true, but not the whole story.

If $0<p\le1$ then the RHS in your second approach diverges.  So your LHS is a series which is term by term less than a divergent series; in this case the comparison test fails and gives you no information.

Note carefully the logic here.  Your second approach shows that the series converges if (**NB** not if and only if) $p>1$.  Your first approach shows that the series converges if $p>0$.  These statements are not contradictory.

It is possible (from the working you have done) that the series might also converge for $p\le0$.  In fact this is not the case: if you do some more work along the lines of your first approach, you can show that the series diverges for $p\le0$.  You will then have a complete solution to the problem: the series converges **if and only if** $p>0$.

Comment: I understand the part with results being non contradictory. I don't understand why the second approach gives less precise result and I suspect that I'm missing something important about what I'm doing.

Why is it that the first one doesn't have the same problem as second one. What is the important piece?

Should I just check for divergence at the boundary and if it diverges I'm done - if not I need to dig around deeper?

Comment: I doubt that you are missing anything important, it's just that the second approach is less informative.  Consider the statement "every day, round the world, McDonalds sells more than $5$ hamburgers".  This is definitely true... but not very informative.  If you want to find the complete solution you need to check for divergence as well as convergence.  You will find that your second approach will **not** tell you that the series diverges for $p\le1$.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. By being not careful and not checking what's going on from below I cannot be sure that the answer encompasses every p. So only by doing it properly and showing that it diverges for some p<=a and converges for p>a can I say that p converges iff p>a ?

Thanks for spending so much time on this!